# Collapsable Menu Not Opening in Bootstrap Framework

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a first-time coder and know next to nothing. I'm trying to learn html, css, and js online. I'm trying to create a a responsive site where the navbar menu collapses on smaller resolutions. As of now the menu icon gets highlighted in white when I click on it but doesn't expand to show the items.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6 and jquery 2.1.4 (I know it's old but the course I'm learning from is using these)

Thanks in advance!!
(PS: Ignore the content, names etc, I'm just trying to keep it interesting for myself)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Gorilla Sports</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_ch.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
    <header> 

        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg" >
                        <div id="logo-img" ></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="index.html"><h1>Gorilla Sports</h1></a>
                        <p>
                            <img src="Images/gorilla_small.jpg" alt="Gorilla">
                            <span>Gorilla</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="menu-categories.html">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Menu</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Awards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="phone" class="hidden-xs">
                            <a href="tel:+91-9910673649">
                                <span>+91-9910673649</span></a><div>* We Deliver</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


        </nav>
    </header>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please create jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/fjg1c5bk/ your collepse menu is working. Maybe your  bootsrap libraries is not correct. Can u change them with  belows and try again

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Yes, it was an error with libraries!!
Should've noticed, sorry for wasting your time.
Thank you so much!!